# unable to redirect to particular screen from local notification in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I have built notification based application in iOS now I am getting issue is that when notification appears on screen, unable to redirect to particular screen containing its data. One thing I have observed is that If I NSLog it,I get all the values of that particular notification but screen does not get load. Am i missing something while integrating local notification hierarchy code ?

Thanks in advance for your help !!

Here is code in Appdelegate.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

       if([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"note"]isEqualToString:@"note"])
       {
         // nsuserdefault...
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterN = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatterN setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
            NSString *currentTimeN = [dateFormatterN stringFromDate:notification.fireDate];


        NSUserDefaults *prefnote=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefnote setObject:currentTimeN forKey:@"dateobject"];
        [prefnote setObject:@"notification" forKey:@"notification"];
        [prefnote synchronize];


        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *storyboardName = [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"];

        UIStoryboard *storyboardNote = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];


      UIViewController *vc1Note = [storyboardNote instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"]; //if you assigned this ID is storyboard
        UIViewController *vc2Note = [storyboardNote instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddNote"];  //if you assigned this ID is storyboard


           NSArray *controllersNote = @[vc1Note,vc2Note];

        UINavigationController *navControllerNote = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

        [navControllerNote setViewControllers:controllersNote];

    }
}
```

I have used IF condition as I have 3 categories and based on particular category It will be redirected to different screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a new UINavigationController instance and set view controllers in this new navigation controller.
However you have not presented the nav controller.

You need to either

- show you new navigation controller by either adding it to an existing view or replacing existing view

or

- push the view controllers to an existing navigation controller (which is already visible) instead of creating a new one. But note that only the last view controller you push will be visible.